# Image to PDF with tcpdf

Tags: php, image, pdf, tcpdf

Hy
I'm trying to convert an image (both png or jpeg) to pdf and then adding crop marks using tcpdf (no limitation on the library, it just seemed the best to me, no problems in changing if would solve the problem). 
the best case for me is: I have an input image, I give it to some function of tcpdf, that converts it into a pdf, add the bookmarks in the angles (top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right) and save the pdf without nowing anything about the sizes of the image... 
I tried looking around but coudn't find anything without passing the size of the images to tcpdf, this is what I came up with:

```
$pagelayout = array('706', '606'); //  or array($height, $width)

$pdf = new TCPDF('', 'pt', $pagelayout, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetAuthor('JOIN SRL');
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image($input, 0, 0, '', '', 'JPG', 'http://www.tcpdf.org', '', true, 300, '', false, false, 1, false, false, false);
$pdf->Image($input);
$pdf->cropMark('', '', 10, 10, 'TL');
$pdf->cropMark('', '', 10, 10, 'TR');
$pdf->cropMark('', '', 10, 10, 'BL');
$pdf->cropMark('', '', 10, 10, 'BR');
$pdf->Output($output, 'F');
```

as you can see I had to pass the image size to tcpdf, but this is just a test, I would like to get rid of this informations in this peace of code... 
And this dosn't work either because the pdf page comes otu bigger than the image, and hte crop marks don't get show( I think this is quite obvious, I tried not giving coordinates hoping that they would automatically set in the angles of the page, but no luck) . 
Does someone have any ideas?
thank's

**EDIT**
I managed to solve nearly everything. could be fine like this( the code follows) but I wanted to know if there is a way to do the same thing without knowing the image size.

```
 $pdf->setMargins(0, 0, 0);
 $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
 $pdf->AddPage();
 $pdf->Image($input);
 $width = $pdf->getPageWidth();
 $height = $pdf->getPageHeight();
 $pdf->cropMark(5, 5, 5, 5, 'TL', array(255, 0, 0));
 $pdf->cropMark($width - 5, 5, 5, 5, 'TR', array(255, 0, 0));
 $pdf->cropMark(5, $height - 5, 5, 5, 'BL', array(255, 0, 0));
 $pdf->cropMark($width - 5, $height - 5, 5, 5, 'BR', array(255, 0, 0));
 $pdf->Output($output, 'F');
```

thank's